# inner product space, non negative transformation

Tags: inner-products

I'm new to inner product space and I have a hard time with this question, can someone help me:
Let $V$ be a unitary space with finite dimension and let $T:V\to V$ be a non negative linear transformation. Assume that there is  $n \in N$ that $T^n=I$.
is necessarily $T=I$ ?

Thanks!

Comment: What is a **non negative** linear transformation?

Comment: linear transformation and (Tu,u)>=0 for evrey u in V when T=T*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$T$ is selfadjoint. Let $ \lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $T$. Then $\lambda^n$ is an eigenvalue of $T^n$. Hence $\lambda^n=1$. Since $T$ is non negative, $ \lambda=1$. Therefore $T-I$ is selfadoint and has only one eigenvalue $0$.

From $||T-I||=r(T-I)=0$, we get $T=I$

($r(T)$ = spectral radius of $T$).

Comment: Simple answer. Thank you for spotting my stupid error. +1